# Adjectival form of "phyllid?"

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, derivational-morphology

What's the word that relates to "phyllid" like "foliate" relates to "foliage?"

> Phyllid: A leaf-like extension of the stem in Bryophytes

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_botanical_terms#phyllid

Comment: As in some community where the word "phillid" is well-known.  Perhaps no one reading here belongs to such a community.

Comment: Phyllid seems to be a truncation of [phyllidium](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/143056#eid30444048) and I suspect they are the same thing or that they should be classed as the same thing. Therefore phyllidial might be the appropriate adjective.

Answer (score 1):

**Phylliform** is the adjectival form of the very similar word *phyllidium*, which was truncated to form *phyllid*. OED, "[phylliform, adj](https://oed.com/view/Entry/143057).":

> Leaf-shaped, leaflike.

Rather like *foliate* is used far beyond botany to describe leaf-like things, *phylliform* is also used to describe anything sufficiently leaf-like, like anatomical features that are shaped like leaves.